# set error message when image is not uploaded

Tags: javascript, image

Set error message when user forgets to upload image. i have not found anything most of the errors are uploading errors i want one that lets the user know that they forgot to upload image also i don't want to let the user go tho the next page until the image is uploaded. i have tried using my old code for forgot first and last name but that doesn't seem to work. that is just an example to show you what i use for errors please help

```
function formValidator() {
     var names = document.getElementById('names');


if (isAlphanumeric(names, "Please enter first and last name")) {



<input type="file" name="file3" id="file3" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're over-engineering a bit here. You can actually rely on attributes of `input` in HTML5 that can validate or invalidate form submission for you. For example, denoting an `input` as `required` and using [`formvalidate`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-formnovalidate) can trigger this automatically.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="myform">
    <input type="file" name="file3" id="file3" required formvalidate>
    <input type="submit" novalidate>
</form>
```

The browser will insure the input is supplied before allowing the submission. You can also hook into the form's `onsubmit` handler via javascript if you need to do further validation...

```
var myform = document.getElementById('myform');
myform.onsubmit = function(e) { /* do some validation on event here */ };
```